# How do I access the next item in the array, in the current iteration with Ruby on Rails and Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, haml

I iterate through an array called questions. I need to compare the current "question.title" to the next "question.title. It looks like this:

```
- questions.each_with_index do |question, index|
      -if question.title != questions[index + 1].title
        do this
      -else
        do that
```

I get this error:
NoMethodError at /applicants/1152123/custom_questions ==> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you sure the error is on this line, because `index` should never be `nil` there?

Comment: When it's on the last question, index + 1 will be nil. You can put a `rescue nil` as a band aid but you should probably change your logic.

Comment: It will not be `nil` on the last question no, however it will be out of bounds of the array, so it will need to check if `index == (questions.length - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

When the iteration reaches the last question, there will be a `NoMethodError` for `questions[index + 1].title` because `questions[index + 1]` is `nil`.

You could just use [`each_cons(2)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to get every pair of successive questions :

```
questions = %w(q1 q2 q3 q4)

questions.each_cons(2) do |one_question, next_question|
  p one_question
  p next_question
  puts
end
```

It outputs :

```
"q1"
"q2"

"q2"
"q3"

"q3"
"q4"
```

PS: This should be one problem less and it will simplify your code. You might still have another problem, but it's hard to tell without the whole view and error message.

Comment: That doesn't explain the error though, because it says `undefined method + for nil:NilClass`, but `index` will never be `nil`